# How do I track prevValue in Vue composable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to track previousValue so that when elRef changes, I can cancel an event listener on prev and add it to new. But previous value is always null. I've confirmed that the watcher does fire when elRef changes. I've confirmed that elRef is indeed a ref.

```
const { ref, watch } = window.Vue;

function useComposable1(elRef) {
    watch(elRef, (newVal, prevVal) => {
        if (prevVal) {
            // this code is never reached, even when elRef is a ref that changes
            console.log('prevVal', prevVal);
        }
    });
}

function useComposable2(elRef) {
    const prevVal = ref(null);

    watch(elRef, () => {
        console.log(prevVal.value); // this always returns null
        prevVal.value = elRef.value;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that watchers don't run immediately, but on the next computation cycle. So if you change `elRef` several times without interruption, you will see the watcher run only once when all changes are done.

Otherwise, your code works as expected:

```js
const { watch, ref } = Vue;
console.clear()

function useComposable1(elRef) {
    watch(elRef, (newVal, prevVal) => {
        if (prevVal) {
            console.log('prevVal', prevVal);
        }
    });
}

function useComposable2(elRef) {
    const prevVal = ref(null);

    watch(elRef, () => {
        console.log(prevVal.value); // this always returns null
        prevVal.value = elRef.value;
    });
}

;(async function(){
  const sourceRef = ref(1)
  useComposable1(sourceRef)
  useComposable2(sourceRef)
  
  sourceRef.value++
  sourceRef.value++
  console.log('break and run watchers')
  await Promise.resolve()
  
  sourceRef.value++
  console.log('break and run watchers')
  await Promise.resolve()
  
  console.log('fin', sourceRef.value)
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```